# Mousewheel and transition incompatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, mousewheel

**SCENARIO**

I have developed a function with jQuery which listens to the user's mouse input (based on the *[mousewheel](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel)* plugin).

I analyze the user's input with a function, and alter the default behavior of the mouse, so that it scrolls a given px value with an animation.

**PROBLEM**

There are `div` containers in the webpage that transform its size when hovered.

This causes my original mousewheel animation to delay its action for a little time (more or less, half a second). If a `div` is hovered, and quickly afterwards the mousewheel is rolled, the effect won't run 100% smoothly (it will cause a little lag while the scroll animation is executing, and right afterwards, it will show the animation, which was already running).

If I delete the transition in the containers, the problem is solved. However, I would like to keep the original CSS intact, and run my original animation smoothly.

How can I accomplish this?

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/kouk/z7p0vxpg/

**JS CODE**

```
$(function () {

    function wheel($div, deltaY) {


       if (deltaY == -1) {

            var dest = ($(document).scrollTop()+500);

            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: dest}, 1000);

            return false;        


        } else if (deltaY == 1) {

            var dest = ($(document).scrollTop()-500);

            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: dest}, 1000);

            return false;    

        }



    }

    $('html').bind('mousewheel', function (event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {

        if ($('html,body').is(":animated")){

            return false;

        }

        if ( (delta > -2) && (delta < 2) ) {

            wheel($(this), deltaY);
            event.preventDefault();

            console.log(delta);

        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with the `animate()` function. The previous animations are in the queue and lagging behind. You should empty the animation queue before starting the next animation to avoid the "lag" feeling.

There are two functions which let you do that : [finish()](https://api.jquery.com/finish/) and [stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) . I recommend using `finish` as it will stop the running animation )*and* remove all queued animations. This was you can immediately start your latest animation.

A user doesn't necessarily want to wait for his previous animation which he has already started a new action.

Here's some sample code:

`$('html,body').dequeue().animate({scrollTop: dest}, 1000);`

See if the behavior is as your expected now.

And your code (updated with `finish()`) - http://jsfiddle.net/z7p0vxpg/15/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, your code doesn't work - it simply stops the mousewheel effect.
Is there a way to simply abort the `div` animation, and afterwards execute the scroll animation, without lag?

Comment: Hmm.. I think I may have misunderstood your question. How about this - http://jsfiddle.net/z7p0vxpg/16/ . Is this the expected effect? I used `dequeue()` to clear the animation queue. You can abort `div` animation using `stop()` , clear queue using `dequeue` and then start your animation too! Its all about how you want to present the effect.